# How to make Selenium wait until the elements on the page are replaced (java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriverwait, web-testing

For a graduation project, I am testing an online store using Selenium Webdriver and Java. I'm stuck in this part of the testing , where I have to check whether all search results (products) contains partucular word.
My search returns several pages of products. There is a pagination at the bottom of the page, but I don't know and can't check the exact number of pages, so I just click the [Next page] button while it is available.

So the promblem is that when I click the [Next Page] button at the bottom of the page, the page scrolls up, the previous products remain for about 1 second, and then are replaced with new ones from the next page. The page itself is not reloaded, only the previous products are replaced by the next ones in the corresponding block on the page. The block and products are  element.

It works if I use Thread.sleep, but this is considered a bad decision. I can't figure out if there's any way I can use explicity wait (textToBePresentInElement, elementToBeClickable, visibilityOfElementLocated, presenceOfElementLocated don't suit) as in my other tests.

```
    List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.className(SearchPage.LABEL_PRODUCT_NAME));
    for (WebElement product : products) {
        Assertions.assertTrue(product.getText().toLowerCase().contains(SearchPage.textForSearchWithResults),
                "Error. No " + SearchPage.textForSearchWithResults + " found.");
    }

    WebElement pagination = driver.findElement(By.xpath(SearchPage.BUTTON_PAGINATION_NEXT));
    while (driver.findElements(By.xpath(SearchPage.BUTTON_PAGINATION_NEXT)).size() > 0) {
        pagination.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        List<WebElement> productsOnTheNextPage = driver.findElements(By.className(SearchPage.LABEL_PRODUCT_NAME));
        for (WebElement product : productsOnTheNextPage) {
            System.out.println(product.getText());
            Assertions.assertTrue(product.getText().toLowerCase().
                            contains(SearchPage.textForSearchWithResults.toLowerCase()),
                    "Error. No " + SearchPage.textForSearchWithResults + " found.");
        }
    }
```

How can I replace this Thread.sleep?

Comment: Did you consider using WebDriverWait? https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas...

---

### Idea #1

Right after you click "next page", you mentioned there is a 1-second window that the previous product remains on the page.

Start checking for `visibilityOfElementLocated() = false` on the **previous product** right after you click "next page".

---

### Idea #2

Idea #1 might fail if your CPU is not fast enough to catch the previous product during that 1-second window.  In that case, try forking a new worker thread to check for the previous product right before you click "next page".  Then, after you click "next page", the master thread will wait for the worker thread to confirm that the previous product has disappeared.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it'll work out. All products - the previous and new - the same elements, they have the same xpath. The only difference is the images and product names. And it's an online store, so they add/remove products, and I can't hardcode them because today this product is on page 2, and tomorrow it might be on page 5.

Comment: Hi @Lydia, when you use visibilityOfElementLocated(), it sets a hook on the element on page 1.  As soon as the page 1's element disappears (which is a prerequisite for loading page 2's elements), the hook will notify Selenium.  Therefore, even though the xpath is the same, the hook will still be activated.

Comment: Thank you for explanation @howard_9. But it looks like, as you mentioned, my CPU is not fast enough. I tried 'invisibilityOfElementWithText' with the first product title from the previous page via 'products.get(0).getText()' and it works so far.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pair WebdriverWait with ExpectedConditions

```
new WebDriverWait(driver1, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

I recommend this explanation of how to use WebDriverWait in conjunction with ExpectedConditions: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/expectedconditions-in-selenium

Comment: thanks. looks like ExpectedConditions is not a good option in my case and maybe I should try other waiters

Answer (score 0):

Use like this...

```
webdeivewait wait =new webdeivewait (driver,some seconds here);

wait.until (ExpectedConditions.Visibilityofelementlocated(By.xpath("xpath of webelement you want to wait")).click();
```